# Dynamically changing CSS value in Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, dynamic

In my app, I have movies' details that can be opened, and I want the buttons of the detail to match the movie.

For instance, with the movie "Back to the Future", I have in my data `colors = ["#000000","#123123"]`.

If I do `<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': movie?.colors[0]}">` the div will be of the color I wanted.

My question is, in Ionic, how can I change `variables.scss` to have these colors (updated when we open a new movie) ?

Because we can't modify tabs with custom css, so I have to add it to  `variables.scss`...

Comment: variables.scss will be compiled to css at build time

Comment: PS : I know how to theme my app, but I can't change colors in variables.scss dynamically ? (or bypass it)

Comment: you can use css variables , I think this the only way because you can set some theme value at run time color , font-size ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to update any css color or value like font-size like the sass variable at run time use **css variables** in this way you can update any css property value at run time if it base on css variable like the color in my example but it 's can be any css value

consider this example

style.css

```
:root {
--color : red;
}

 * {
   color:var(--color)
 }
```

*AppComponent*

```
  colorList = ['green', 'blue'];

  updateColor(color) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--color`, color);
  }
```

*Template*

```
<button *ngFor="let c of colorList" (click)="updateColor(c)">{{c}}</button>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53502364)

> sass variable are going to compile at build time to there values so they are not reusable at run time

Comment: thank you very much, it works to a perfection :D I didn't know we could pass variables from js to css like that ^^

Comment: one of the most impressive times when stackoverflow is like gold. `document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--color`, color);` worked perfect in Ionic cordova too.

Comment: Thanks ... save my day

Answer (score 2):

For most use cases, it is convenient to programmatically change the CSS value of an element by mapping it with a variable. We want the CSS value to change every time we update the variable, **not** only through `this.ngZone.run()`.

```
<div class="progress" [style.height]=currentLevelPercentage>
```

This example has shown how we can map the height CSS property of the div element (class *progress*) to the variable `currentLevelPercentage` and change its value dynamically. **`currentLevelPercentage` is the variable that must be compulsorily present in the TypeScript file.**

Answer (score 1):

For those here to know how to change color of each tab background in super-tabs (ionic) here's my 4 tabs code (I can now change height and width with code too ^^).

in tabs-page.scss :

```
  :root {
    --color1: white;
    --color2: white;
    --color3: white;
    --color4: white;
  }

  super-tab-button:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: var(--color1)
  }

  super-tab-button:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: var(--color2)
  }

  super-tab-button:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: var(--color3)
  }

  super-tab-button:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-color: var(--color4)
  }
```

in tabs-page.html : do nothing particular

in tabs-page.ts :

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color1', this.movie.colors[0]);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color2', this.movie.colors[1]);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color3', this.movie.colors[2]);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color4', this.movie.colors[3]);
  }
```

Thank you @malbarmawi !

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea about changing style dynamically. here is what i am using

```
<span [style.width]=foo></span>
```

Change the value of ‘foo’ in your .ts file
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#style-binding

Answer (score 0):

**Simply try this**

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.color}"
```